# D3 on keyboard event return hyperlink

Tags: javascript, d3.js, keyboard

I'm trying to do a kind of "key navigation" on my website: if it's pressed left_arrow,  I return to the previous page and if it's pressed right_arrow i go to next page. I've done this, the "console.log("keydown")" works, but the function returns don't.

```
d3.select("body")
  .on("keydown", function(e) { 
      console.log("keydown");
      //return "line_chart.html";
      if(e == 37) { // left     
          console.log("left"); 
          return "line_chart1.html";
      }
      else if(e == 39) { // right     
          console.log("right"); 
          return "line_chart2.html";
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
.on("keydown", function(e) { //e is coming UNDEFINED
          console.log("keydown");
          //return "line_chart.html";
          if(e == 37) { // left i found e as undefined
```

I got the keycode using `d3.event.keycode` and it worked something like below:

```
d3.select("body")
        .on("keydown", function(e) { 
          console.log("keydown");
          //return "line_chart.html";
          if(d3.event.keycode == 37) { // left     
            console.log("left"); 
            return "line_chart1.html";//this return will not do anything
          }
          else if(d3.event.keycode == 39) { // right     
            console.log("right"); 
            return "line_chart2.html";//this return will not do anything
          }
        });
```

**EDIT**

```
d3.select("body")
        .on("keydown", function(e) { 
          console.log("keydown");
          //return "line_chart.html";
          if(d3.event.keyCode == 37) { // left     
            console.log("left"); 
            SOME_FUNCTION("line_chart1.html");
          }
          else if(d3.event.keyCode == 39) { // right     
            console.log("right"); 
            SOME_FUNCTION("line_chart2.html");
          }
        });
```

Comment: or it can  be done like this `$('body')` with rest of code remaining the same I guess if OP do not want to use d3.event by chance. Any how its the same.

Comment: Yes I agree in case OP is using jquery then $('body') is an option. i think it can be another answer.

Comment: I don't know why but I still have just the keydown output and not the "right" or "left" one and also the return of the link doesn't work..

Comment: `keyCode` should be in camel case and use `window.location = "line_chart1.html";` instead of return statement as you need page redirection.

Comment: The function will return  "line_chart2.html" but how can you use it...you have to write a function check my edit block.

Comment: Yep! thanks now it works the key-listener but I've done many try and I still don't know how to return a link to another page..

Comment: YOu need to write SOME_FUNCTION which will do the rendering of the page depending on the parameter.. you just cant return it!

Comment: Sorry you're too fast to answer! Now everything works perfectly! Thanks to everyone

Comment: Thanks! @Gilsha keyCode was a typo :)